# Need help making a Fortune Telling program using eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse

This fortune telling program is based on the origami fortune teller that elementary kids used. The person had to choose a number displayed inside the fortune teller. The chosen number was counted out opening and closing the fortune teller. The person then chose another number from the available numbers on display inside the fortune teller (they may or may not have been the same numbers as before) which was again counted out. A final number was chosen and the fortune under the flap was read!

> Design and create a fortune telling program that works as follows:
>
> Generate a number between 0 and 2 and allow the user to choose that
>   number, that number plus one or that number plus 2 (in other words one
>   of three consecutive numbers starting from the randomly chosen number)
>        Generate another number (0-2) and based on that number display three colors (of a possible 4 colors) from which to choose based on
>   the number and color combination selected, tell the user their
>   fortune.
>
> Some requirements: Choices must be random Color combination must also
>   be random The first input must be a number, the second must be a
>   color. Make sure to type these user variables appropriately. Type also
>   has ramifications on the if /switch statement(s). Be careful!! Use
>   switch statement(s) as appropriate (at least one must be used) There
>   are six possible numbers and four possible colors = Make up 5 fortunes
>   and reuse them Do NOT use arrays, lists, or
>   functions/subroutines/methods yet

This is what I have so far and now I'm stuck. I need to add a switch stmt but I don't know how.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Lab3 {


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Program that generates a fortune depending on number and color the user picked

        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        String userResponse = "0,1,2";
        //variables
        String[] fortune = new String[5];
        fortune[0]= "Something great is coming";
        fortune[1]= "Lucky day today";
        fortune[2]= "Be careful today";
        fortune[3]= "You will get an A on your next test";
        fortune[4]= "Someone special will be coming into your life shortly";

        int randFortune;
        final int MAX_WINGE = 3;

        System.out.print("Pick a number 0-2:");

        System.out.print("Choose a color(red, blue, yellow, green)");



        randFortune = (int)(Math.random() * (MAX_WINGE)) + 1;



    case 0:
        System.out.println(fortune[0]);
        break;
    case 1:
        System.out.println(fortune[1]);
        break;
    case 2:
        System.out.println(fortune[2]);
        break;
    case 3:
        System.out.println(fortune[3]);
        break;
    case 4:
        System.out.println(fortune[4]);
        break;



    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Just code `switch`:

```
switch (randFortune) {
    case 0:
        System.out.println(fortune[0]);
        break;
    case 1:
       // etc
}
```

Refer to [`switch` keyword documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/switch.html) for a complete explanation.

---

P.S. It looks like you don't need a `switch`, but rather just a single line:

```
System.out.println(fortune[randFortune]);
```

Comment: awesome thanks! When I run my program I get this: Pick a number 0-2:Choose a color(red, blue, yellow, green)Be careful today.